# switchboard-plug-gcc-sound - "unmet dependencies"

Tags: settings, sound, dependencies, switchboard, package

Sorry to bring [this](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/12399/no-sound-setting-in-system-settings/22855?noredirect=1#comment24381_22855) up after ~3 years, but I'm stuck on the suggested solution:

I have a similar issue, but when I'm running this:

```
sudo apt install switchboard-plug-gcc-sound
```

I get this:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 switchboard-plug-gcc-sound : Depends: unity-control-center but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

The above iterates for all the "unmet dependencies".

Any clue about what I might be missing here, would be much appreciated!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Try running `sudo dpkg –configure -a`  If you have Synaptic Packaage Manager, you can also use that to fix broken packages.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I still get the same message: The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 switchboard-plug-gcc-sound : Depends: unity-control-center but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have also faced the same issue. I managed to get the packages installed by using `aptitude` instead of `apt-get` or `apt`.

`aptitude` also detects the dependency issues, but offers a few more automated solutions. The second solution it offered was to remove libglib2.0-bin, install libglib2.0-bin:i386, and upgrade libglib2.0-0, libglib2.0-0:i386, and libglib2.0-dev. This worked and I got my sound settings back.

However there may be consequences I'm not aware of, so please exercise caution.

Comment: I'll check it asap and mark it as solved if your suggestion works, thank you for this insight.

Comment: My god thank you so much! This fixed it! At the cmd I've refused the 1st solution (mostly summed up to "leave things as they were") & accepted the 2nd one and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

After the update, I had exactly the same problem.

These packages are removed:
ibus
ibus-table
switchboard-plug-gcc-color
switchboard-plug-gcc-sound
switchboard-plug-gcc-wacom
unity-control-center

These packages have been updated:
ibus-gtk (1.5.11-1ubuntu2.3) to 1.5.11-1ubuntu2.4
ibus-gtk3 (1.5.11-1ubuntu2.3) to 1.5.11-1ubuntu2.4
libibus-1.0-5 (1.5.11-1ubuntu2.3) to 1.5.11-1ubuntu2.4

Comment: @Lopofsky

1) delete gir1.2-ibus-1.0_1.5.11-1ubuntu2.4_amd64
2) download and install gir1.2-ibus-1.0_1.5.11-1ubuntu2_amd64
3) download and install ibus_1.5.11-1ubuntu2_amd64
4) download and install ibus-table_1.9.21-2_all.deb
5) install from the repository switchboard-plug-gcc-sound
6) PROFIT

Comment: Thank you for the insights! So where can i find the repos for the steps 2 & 3?
I mean through apt list --installed | grep fir1.2-ibus, I do find that you are correct about step 1, but the "apt-cache search ibus | grep "^ibus-1.5.*"" doesn't return any results for step 3 | "apt-cache search ibus | grep "^ibus-table_1.*" the same for step 4 and so on.